# Formatting and groupping float numbers

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

In a Perl Catalyst application, using Template-Toolkit, I print lists of floating numbers using a format:

```
<h4>[% price | format('%9.2f') %]</h4>
```

what formats correctly the numbers (ex. 2113.99) But, I would like to use digit groupping like **2 113.99**. I read [Template::Plugin::Number::Format](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Plugin::Number::Format) but there is no word about digit groupping. How could achieve this?

KI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the very top of documentation link you provided:

> ## Constructor Parameters
>
> The USE line accepts the following parameters, all optional, which define the default behavior for filters within the current Context:
>
> ```
> THOUSANDS_SEP
> ```
>
> character inserted between groups of 3 digits
>
> ......